# generate md5 of list values in python

Tags: python, list, hash, md5

i have a list named as abc which have data like this :

```
{'devicetype': ['nokia'],'userid': ['1234'], 'year': ['2013']}
```

Now i have to generate the md5 of the values like nokia , '1234' , '2013'
for this i had taken these value in variable like this

```
 devicetype = abc['devicetype']
 userid = abc['userid']
 year = abc['year']
```

after that i tried to use md5 to generate a hash like this

```
  authvalue = hashlib.md5()
  authvalue.update(devicetype+userid+year)
```

it gives me an error "must be string or buffer, not list" 
i know this will accept just string . but how can i generate the md5 of these list value?

Comment: what is auth1 ? You realise that the three variables you have are arrays, too, right? year == ['2013']

Comment: @moopet : by mistake i put auth1 there . it is authvalue . And yes i know this is a array. how can i generate the hash of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martijn Pieters' answer is basically correct, you have lists of a single element. If you have a big dictionary though, manually adding [0] to each entry might be a pain. So instead you can use map() and reduce() to do that for you.

If d is your dictionary with key-value pairs as above, you can do:

```
values = map(lambda x: x[0], d.values())
```

d.values() is just a list of the values of your dictionary (in your case, a list of 1-element long lists):

```
[['1234'], ['nokia'], ['2013']]
```

By mapping that lambda function to each one of them you get rid of the inner list:

```
['1234', 'nokia', '2013']
```

Then you can get the concatenation of all strings by reducing that list:

```
concat = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, values, "")
```

So concat will be:

```
'1234nokia2013'
```

which then you can feed to your hashing function.

Comment: I'd use `''.join(values)` instead of that whole `reduce(lambda...)` mess.

Comment: Well, that depends on how much of a functional programmer one is, I guess :)

Answer (score 3):

You have *lists*, not strings. Take the *first* element of each list:

```
authvalue = hashlib.md5()
auth1.update(devicetype[0] + userid[0] + year[0])
```